# Prob with buzzing on zoom 4hn and ME66 powered with k6

Tags: audio-recording, zoom-h4n, interference

My Question relates to below answer by JM V almost 2 years ago... zoom h4n problem 2
See below answer.
I have humming noise on first recording I made today. Not an expert on Mics or recording
so wondering how to eliminate by " panning the recording"
Thanks
S

okay I tested it out and this "buzz" complaint is a smear campaign against this awesome little machine, the only buzz that is there is if you plug an XLR into only one input, you can eliminate it by simply panning the recording! –  JM V Apr 26 '12 at 13:35

Answer (score 1):

In terms of panning, if you're only recording to one track, then you should set it to record in mono on both tracks. I do not think the recorder actually allows you to record mono files, so basically you have a mono sound recording to 2 tracks.

Comment: Yep, mono mix I think is what It should be set too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it under phantom power or battery power? I would suggest trying with phantom power provided by the h4n. I believe the panning issue being referred to is that if you have one XLR plugged in, then the one with no input may be noisy. Using only the appropriate channel may be quieter.

As Takuya Katsu pointed out, it is also worth putting in in Mono Mix mode so that you get the left channel recorded on both the right and left tracks though it isn't strictly necessary if you are going to pull one of the channels out in post anyway.

Comment: Thanks Aj, I will try that. Was on youtube late last night and I might try mono mix to see if it fixes. I will try power using phantom power as well and see how I go(: